Monitoring Power Outages and Reporting via Email
I'm looking for a way to monitor power outages at my location. Ideally, I'd like to track:

Duration of each outage: How long the power is out each time.
Frequency of outages: How often power outages occur.
And I want this information to be reported to me via email, perhaps in a weekly or monthly summary.
Is there any software or combination of tools available on Ubuntu that can achieve this?  I'm open to using a UPS or other hardware if necessary.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!


you might find this Reddit sysadmin post of some help.
